# How to resume computation on exception in C#?

Tags: c#

```
try
{
    statement 1;
    statement 2;
    statement 3;
    statement 4;
    statement 5;
}
catch
{
}
```

The above is the typical try-catch. If one of the statment goes into catch, the coding will jump the rest statement.

What I want to do is..

let's say, statement 2 has an error and goes into exception, I still want to work on statement 3,4, and 5.

I m just curious how can I achieve that?

The simplest answer would be 5 try-catch.

But I think it is too childish.

Comment: so you want "on error resume next" in c#?

Comment: *When* do you want the exception to be handled? What if `2`  and `4` both throw exceptions? Do you want to handle both of them once `5` finishes? Or do you just want to ignore all errors?

Comment: I struggle to think of a scenario where this would be a good idea. can you give us some more context?

Comment: Ok.. I have a datatable with full of data.. I am calcualting all data column by column to get the total. So.. There are around 9 total values. In 1 for loop, if I put 1 try catch, then if one column has error, the rest will also be skipped.

Comment: There is nothing childish about only explicitly handling the exceptions you know you can handle as close to when they are thrown as possible. That you want to do this is a smell that there is something more rotten going on in the code. Be warned.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using separate `try .. catch` constructs would be the best thing to do in general, because you should handle the most specific exceptions (which can be different for different statements). Also, an exception can create an invalid state, so continuing may not be the best thing to do.

If you're just looking for a simpler syntax to write it and you need to repeat the same exception handling, you can use lambdas and write something like:

```
CallWithCatch
 ( () => statement1,
   () => statement2,
   () => statement3,
   /* ... */ );
```

Where the definition of `CallWithCatch` looks like this:

```
void CallWithCatch(params Action[] statements) {
  foreach(var statement in statements) { 
    try { 
      statement();
    } catch(/* your exception */) {
      // your exception handler
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

So generally speaking, all of your statements probably throw exceptions, and you want to continue to execute following statements if one throws exception. The simplest solution is:

```
try
{
   statement1;
}
catch {}
try
{
   statement2;
}
catch {};
...
```

which looks bad. An improvement is:

```
public void TryStatements(params Action[] actions)
{
   foreach(Action act in actions)
   {
     try
     {
        act();
     }
     catch(SomeCommonException ex)
     {
        //do something special
     }
     catch(Exception ex)
     {
        //something else
     }
   }
}
```

then you can:

```
   TryStatement(()=>statement1,()=>satement2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch each exception individually.

```
try 
{     
    statement 1;     
}
catch {}

try
{
    statement 2;
}
catch {} 

// etc
```

Alternatively you can extract `statement1`, `statement2` etc into their own methods, each of which contains their own `try/catch`.  This way each of those operations can concern themselves with any particular exceptions, and you can handle all the expected exceptions, letting unhandled exceptions bubble up as normal.